# Pandas: Conditional Replace With a Set

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of common email addresses, like this:

```
common_addresses = set(["yahoo.com", "gmail.com", "hotmail.com"])
```

I have a Pandas DataFrame, `df`, that looks like:

```
id email_domain
1  yahoo.com
2  gmail.com
3  unk.com
4  new.com
```

I want to replace the emails that aren't in my `common_addresses` with "rare".  Here's my attempt:

```
mask = df.email_domain not in common_addresses
df.loc[mask, "email_domain"] = "rare"
```

I get an error on the `mask = ...` line as follows:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

How should I be creating this mask?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You're almost there. For a Series you want to use [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to check membership. In your case, you should change your code to:

```
mask = ~df.email_domain.isin(common_addresses)
df.loc[mask, "email_domain"] = "rare"
```

Also, you need to use the `~` operator (instead of `not`) to operate on the Series.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use

```
df['email_domain'] = df.email_domain.where(df.email_domain.isin(common_addresses), 'rare')

df
```

Output:

```
   id email_domain
0   1    yahoo.com
1   2    gmail.com
2   3         rare
3   4         rare
```